# How to reduce top margin for div inside bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have `html` file using `bootstrap` `rows` and `columns` for arranging elements. One of `row class` showing unwanted `margin` at top and bottom when I place `divs` inside `row class`.

This is my code

```
<div class="row">    
    <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="col-md-11 card card-body bg-light">
      <div style="background-color: blue;" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">   

          <div style="background-color: green;">    
            <mat-tab-group #tabRef>
              <mat-tab label="Angular">Angular Content</mat-tab>
              <mat-tab label="React">React Content</mat-tab>
              <mat-tab label="VueJs">VueJs Content</mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>    
          </div>        
          <div id="map">   
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">                               
          <div style="border: none; margin-top: 25px; width: 95%;">
          
          </div>

         </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

This is output screenshot

[image]

I tried using row `no-gutters` and `m-0 p-0` but `margin` not getting reduced. How can I fix this?

Comment: you have a margin-top inside your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif - If I remove that still I am getting same margin top and bottom side. Sorry for not removing that for example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In BS, class `card` is having default `padding: 1.25rem;`. Remove it by adding `py-0` or `p-0` next to your card class.

### DEMO:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">    
    <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="col-md-11 card card-body bg-light py-0">
      <div style="background-color: blue;" class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">   

          <div style="background-color: green;">    
            <mat-tab-group #tabRef>
              <mat-tab label="Angular">Angular Content</mat-tab>
              <mat-tab label="React">React Content</mat-tab>
              <mat-tab label="VueJs">VueJs Content</mat-tab>
            </mat-tab-group>    
          </div>        
          <div id="map">   
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">                               
          <div style="border: none; margin-top: 25px; width: 95%;">
          
          </div>

         </div>
      </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```html
  <div class="row">    
        <div style="margin-left: 20px;" class="col-md-11 card card-body bg-light p-0">
          <div style="background-color: blue;" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">   
    
              <div style="background-color: green;">    
                <mat-tab-group #tabRef>
                  <mat-tab label="Angular">Angular Content</mat-tab>
                  <mat-tab label="React">React Content</mat-tab>
                  <mat-tab label="VueJs">VueJs Content</mat-tab>
                </mat-tab-group>    
              </div>        
              <div id="map">   
              </div>
    
            </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-3">                               
              <div style="border: none; margin-top: 25px; width: 95%;">
              
              </div>
    
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
```